# PThread Crashes Within Class in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, class

So I am pretty new to threading in general and have been experimenting with pthreads for the past couple of weeks. I have created a class that has a threaded function within itself. It works fine, until I tried to set a class property (an integer) to a value.

.h file:

```
#ifndef TESTCLASS_H
#define TESTCLASS_H

#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

class testClass
{
    public:
        testClass();
        HANDLE h;
        static DWORD WINAPI mythread(LPVOID param);
        int mytestint;
        void printstuffs();
        void startThread();
};

#endif // TESTCLASS_H
```

.cpp file

```
#include "testClass.h"

testClass::testClass()
{
    cout << "Created class" << endl;
}
DWORD WINAPI testClass::mythread(LPVOID param)
{
    cout << "In thread" << endl;
    testClass* This = (testClass*)param;

    cout << "Calling class function" << endl;
    This->printstuffs();

    cout << "Thread is done" << endl;

    return NULL;
}
void testClass::printstuffs()
{
    cout << "In class function " << endl;
    mytestint = 42; // <- crashes here
    cout << "Test Int = " << mytestint << endl;
}
void testClass::startThread()
{
    h = CreateThread(NULL, 0, mythread, (LPVOID)0, 0, NULL);
    cout << "Thread started" << endl;
}
```

So why does it crash when I call `mytestint = 42;` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling `mythread` with a null pointer.  When you cast that to `This`, you end up calling a function on a null object.  When you do `mytestint = 42`, the computer sees it like `this->mytestint = 42`, and since `this` is `NULL`, you dereference a null pointer, and the program segfaults.  You need to do something like the following:

```
h = CreateThread(NULL, 0, mythread, (LPVOID)this, 0, NULL);
```

If possible, I would also suggest migrating over to standard C++ threads introduced in C++11.  Since it looks like you're just learning multithreading it would be useful to learn the standard facilities (which are included with the latest versions of MSVC and GCC) vice vendor-specific APIs.

Comment: Okay, it works now. Not use to using "this" so your explanation helped. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The way you are implementing the thread call back is not correct. And are you sure that its crashing at the integer assignment, I assume it must be crashing in te first line of your Thread Call back.

You are not passing a reference to "this" in the CreateThread function call.

Comment: Depending on the calling convention in most cases a non-virtual function call will not crash until you actually try to read or write to a member.